# Showing API retrieve from Stripe in html format?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a stripe retrieve for account balance and data but when i display it in the views, it displays JSON data.  I could be wrong but here's what I'm seeing and my code:

What I want to do is display it in just text.

Controller:

```
  @balance = Stripe::Balance.retrieve(
      {:stripe_account => current_user.stripe_token }
    )
```

View:

```
<%= @balance.pending %>

<% @balance.each do |b| %>
  <%= @balance.pending %>
  <% end %>

<%= @balance["pending"] %>
```

All 3 view attempts show the same thing.

I have also tried render json: and :html to see, but it didn't do what I thought it was going to do. It loaded the page without any of the html/css...

So what do i do to display the view as a normal page like all my other pageS?

This is the page result:

```
[#<Stripe::StripeObject:0x3f86a1c03afc> JSON: { "currency": "usd", "amount": 150, "source_types": {"card":150} }] [#<Stripe::StripeObject:0x3f86a1c03afc> JSON: { "currency": "usd", "amount": 150, "source_types": {"card":150} }] [#<Stripe::StripeObject:0x3f86a1c03afc> JSON: { "currency": "usd", "amount": 150, "source_types": {"card":150} }] [#<Stripe::StripeObject:0x3f86a1c03afc> JSON: { "currency": "usd", "amount": 150, "source_types": {"card":150} }] [#<Stripe::StripeObject:0x3f86a1c03afc> JSON: { "currency": "usd", "amount": 150, "source_types": {"card":150} }] [#<Stripe::StripeObject:0x3f86a1c03afc> JSON: { "currency": "usd", "amount": 150, "source_types": {"card":150} }]
```

Comment: Can you add full code of the controllers method?

Comment: That's it, inside def account - end ...

Comment: I want to show only "amount"

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer to what i needed to do:

```
<% @balance.pending.each do |balance| %>
    <%= balance["currency"] %>
    <%= balance["amount"]  %>
    <%= balance["source_types"]["card"] %>
<% end %>
```